# Confused on how to evaluate the while !result in the while function

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm not sure how to evaluate this line to understand what my code does
  while (i < data.length && !result) {

this is my full code.

```
public static boolean {2,6,-3,7,3} (int[] data, int val) {
  boolean result = false;
  int i = 0;

  while (i < data.length && !result) {
    if (data[i] == val) {
      result = true;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `public static boolean {2,6,-3,7,3}` is not valid in any language I know.

Comment: Also... what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The `result` variable is used as a way to break out of the while loop before `i` reaches `data.length`. It causes the loop to be exited when `result` becomes `true`.

It is equivalent to:

```
boolean result = false;
int i = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] == val) {
        result = true;
        break; // here we break from the loop explicitly when result becomes true
    }
    i++;
}

return result;
```

or even simpler:

```
int i = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] == val) {
        return true; // here we break from the loop using a return statement 
                     // when a match is found
    }
    i++;
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean result = false; //initial declaration
int i = 0;

while (i < data.length && !result) { 
    if (data[i] == val) {
        result = true;
        // the !result evaluates to false once you've reached this statement
    }
```

So as soon as you find a match of `val` in the `data[]`. The flow breaks out of the loop since the condition becomes

```
any() && false => false
```

where `any()` could be either true or false based on your first condition `i < data.length`.